# Alternatives for Application Insight reg:

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an existing on-prem/Cloud environment in which am running my enterprise application and I would like to implement Application Insight to capture telemetry. But I have few issues on it. Are there any alternatives to use application insights? I have two concerns here:

1) it might not be possible to install softwares in production environment 2) restarting IIS Server would pull all the sites down at least for a minutes or two. It would be great if some one can suggest alternatives of leveraging these App Insights. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not offering an alternative to Application Insights, but wanted to clarify what your environment is: custom/on prem, Azure cloud role or Azure WebApp? In case it is Azure cloud role, the recommended approach would be to onboard your application to AppInsights, deploy to staging slot and then VIPSwap to production slot - this way you'll have virtually no downtime.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to use Application insights:

1) using the sdk, where you add the sdk to your service.  At some point you have to deploy the service, so when you deploy, you'd also deploy app insights into that service

2) using status monitor, which does require restarting IIS.  using status monitor isn't required, but does let you collect extra and detailed information that you wouldn't get from the sdk alone.

A lot of people end up doing both, (1) so they can do custom collection of events, traces, etc, and (2) to get detailed dependency calls

But like AlexB suggested, setting up something where you can swap between slots is one of the best ways to set things up, if possible, so you can just swap between the slots without having any downtime at all.